# codeigniter: how to access(edit,delete) the contents of the database as anyone who has done the login process?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, session

I have a system page . The page displays a table management

```
no | school name |    address   |   action
--------------------------------------
1  | school a    | address 1    | edit/delete       
2  | school b    | address 2    | edit/delete 
3  | school c    | address 3    | edit/delete
4  | school d    | address 4    | edit/delete
5  | school e    | address 5    | edit/delete
6  | school f    | address 6    | edit/delete
```

to get on the page, visitors must perform the login process . for example, I had a visitor with username: **steve** , **mila** , **king**

**steve** input school data `school a`, `school b`, and `school f` into database management table.

**mila** input school data `school c`, `school d`, and `school e` into database management table.

how to access(edit,delete) the contents of the database as anyone who has done the login process ?

I mean, like my case. I would like steve can only see and perform management processes only the data that had he put into the database. when **steve** successful login, the database displays only `school a`, `school b` and `school c` on table display.

**mila** also like that, and **king** can't see anything because he's not input data into database.

other than that, can you give me an example of this case fit in codeigniter?

I hope my question is clear. I would be very grateful if you can help me. thanks

Comment: Your table need one more field to store `user_id`. So you can filter data by this field like `select * from management where user_id = 'steve'`

Comment: @RubahMalam yes i have that collumn. The management table have collumn with user_id as foreign key. I dont really understand from your sugestion for using where user_id clause. Can u give me a example?

Comment: You use codeigniter right? please share your code in model that you use to retrieve `management table`. I mean what you've done so far.

Comment: @RubahMalam do I need to use session for this case?

Comment: Yes, to get `user_id`.